# In my code there is an event listener for running every animation iteration but it keep getting the error reading properties of null. Can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, addeventlistener

I am trying to make a traffic game using javascript though every time I try to use this line of code:

```
carAnimation.addEventListener('animationiteration', () => {
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
        left = random * 90 + 15;
        carAnimation.style.left = left + "px";
        counter++;
        console.log(counter)
    });
```

I am getting the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading
> 'addEventListener')
> at HTMLButtonElement. (script.js:40:18)

but I can't seem to find the error in the line. Also, I am trying to run the same code for 3 different elements but it just doesn't seem to work either.

Here is the rest of the code if needed to solve this mystery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div  class="game">
        <div class="car"></div>
        <div class="npcCar"></div>
        <div class="npcCar npcCar2"></div>
        <div class="npcCar npcCar3"></div>
    </div>
    <button class="start">Start!</button>
    <div class="controlContainer">
        <button class="btn pause"></button>
        <button class="btn play"></button>
        <button class="btn restart"></button>
        <button class="btn help"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="helpModal hidd">
        <div class="modal hidden">
            <button class="close-modal">&times;</button>
            <h1>Help</h1>
            <p>
              HOW TO PLAY:
                Use WASD to the arrow keys to move the red car around.
                You need to avoid hitting the blue cars.
                When you hit a car you will automatically lose
                The longer you last the more points you get
                Good luck racer!
            </p>
          </div>
    </div>
   
    
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald&display=swap');

        *{
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            display: flex;
            min-height: 100vh;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: rgb(69, 169, 240);
            font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
        }

        .game{
            position: absolute;
            left: calc(50% - 450px/2);;
            height: 600px;
            width: 450px;
            border: 3px solid black;
            border-radius: 5%;
            background: url('road.png');
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .start{
            position: absolute;
            height: 30px;
            width: 150px;
            background-color: rgb(1, 255, 1);
            border: 3px solid black;
            border-radius: 5%;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight: bold;
            top: 600px;
            left : calc(50% - 150px/2);
            transition: 0.5s;
        }
        .start:hover{
            background: red;
        }

        .controlContainer{
            padding: 5px;
            width: 120px;
            height: 120px;
            border: 3px solid black;
            border-radius: 5%;
            background-color: lawngreen;
        }
        .btn{
            height: 50px;
            width: 50px;
            border: 2px solid black;
            border-radius: 50%;
        }
        .play{
            background-image: url('play.png');
        }
        .pause{
            background-image: url('pause.png');
        }
        .help{
            background-image: url('help.png');
        }
        .restart{
            background-image: url('restart.png');
        }


        .animate{
            animation: road linear infinite 0.5s;
        }
        .hidden{
            display: none;
        }

        @keyframes road{
            0%{
                background-position-y: 0px;
            }
            100%{
                background-position-y: 600px;
            }
        }
        .modal {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            width: 45%;
            background-color: white;
            padding: 6rem;
            border-radius: 5px;
            box-shadow: 0 3rem 5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
            z-index: 100000000;
        }
        .close-modal {
            position: absolute;
            top: 1.2rem;
            right: 2rem;
            font-size: 5rem;
            color: #333;
            cursor: pointer;
            border: none;
            background: none;
        }  
        
        .car{
            position: relative;;
            height: 120px;
            width: 60px;
            border-radius: 5%;
            top: 435px;
            background: url('Player (1).png');
            transform: rotate(180deg);
            z-index: 100000;
            
        }
        .npcCar{
            width: 60px;
            height: 120px;
            background: url('obsacle.png');
            position: relative;
            left: 15px;
            top: -300px;
        }

        .npcCar2{
            top: -420px;
            left: 195px;;
        }

        .npcCar3{
            top: -540px;
            left: 375px

        }

        .carAnimate{
            animation: vroom 0.8s linear infinite;
        }
        .carAnimate2{
            animation: vroom 0.8s linear infinite;
        }
        .carAnimate3{
            animation: vroom 0.8s linear infinite;
        }
        @keyframes vroom{
            0%{
                top: -120px;
            }
            100%{
                top: 600px;
            }
        }
    </style>
     <script>
        'use strict'

        const startBtn = document.querySelector('.start')
        const pauseBtn = document.querySelector('.pause')
        const playBtn = document.querySelector('.play')
        const restartBtn = document.querySelector('.restart')
        const helpBtn = document.querySelector('.help')
        const modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
        const closeModal = document.querySelector('.close-modal');
        const game = document.querySelector('.game');
        const player = document.querySelector('.car');
        const npcPlayer = document.querySelector('.npcCar');
        const npcPlayer2 = document.querySelector('.npcCar2');
        const npcPlayer3 = document.querySelector('.npcCar3');
        const carAnimation = document.querySelector('.carAnimate');
        const carAnimation2 = document.querySelector('.carAnimate2');
        const carAnimation3 = document.querySelector('.carAnimate3');
        let click = 0;
        let interval;
        let both = 0;
        let counter = 0;


        //onLoad
        window.addEventListener("load", () => {
            player.style.position = "relative";
            player.style.left = '195px';
            player.style.top = '485px';
        });

        // Start the Game
        startBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
            console.log('button clicked');
            game.classList.add('animate');
            click+=2;
            npcPlayer.classList.add('carAnimate')
            npcPlayer2.classList.add('carAnimate2')
            npcPlayer3.classList.add('carAnimate3')

            carAnimation.addEventListener('animationiteration', () => {
                var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
                left = random * 90 + 15;
                carAnimation.style.left = left + "px";
                counter++;
                console.log(counter)
            });
            carAnimation2.addEventListener('animationiteration', () => {
            var random1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
            left = random1 * 90 + 15;
            carAnimation2.style.left = left + "px";
            counter++;
            console.log(counter)
            });
            carAnimation3.addEventListener('animationiteration', () => {
            var random1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
            left = random1 * 90 + 15;
            carAnimation3.style.left = left + "px";
            counter++;
            });
            
        });


        //Pausing the Game
        pauseBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
            console.log('button clicked');
            if(click>1){
                game.classList.remove('animate');
                click--
            }
            console.log(click)
        });

        //Resuming the Game
        playBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
            console.log('button clicked');
            if(click===1){
                game.classList.add('animate');
                click++;
                console.log(click);
            }
            
        });

        //Opening the Help Model
        helpBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
            console.log('modal clicked')
            modal.classList.remove('hidden')
        });
        //closing the help modal
        closeModal.addEventListener('click', function(){
            console.log('button clicked')
            modal.classList.add('hidden')
        });

        //Moving Functions
        function moveLeft() {
            var left = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(player).getPropertyValue("left"));
            var transform = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(player).getPropertyValue("transform")); 
        
            if (left > -0) {
            player.style.left = left - 2 + "px";
            player.style.transform = 'rotate(-' + 215 + 'deg)'
            }
        }
        function moveRight() {
            var left = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(player).getPropertyValue("left"));
            if (left < 385) {
            player.style.left = left + 2 + "px";
            player.style.transform = 'rotate(' + 215 + 'deg)'
            }
        }
        function moveUp() {
            var top = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(player).getPropertyValue("top"));
            if (top > 0) {
            player.style.top = top - 2 + "px";
            player.style.transform = 'rotate(' + 180 + 'deg)'
            }
        }
        function moveDown() {
            var top = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(player).getPropertyValue("top"));
            if (top < 490) {
            player.style.top = top + 2 + "px";
            player.style.transform = 'rotate(' + 180 + 'deg)'
            }
        }
        

        //Make the pLayer move
        document.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
            if (both == 0) {
            both++;
            if (event.key === "ArrowLeft") {
                interval = setInterval(moveLeft, 1);
            }
            if (event.key === "ArrowRight") {
                interval = setInterval(moveRight, 1);
            }
            if (event.key === "ArrowUp") {
                interval = setInterval(moveUp, 1);
            }
            if (event.key === "ArrowDown") {
                interval = setInterval(moveDown, 1);
            }
            if (event.key === "a") {
                interval = setInterval(moveLeft, 1);
            }
            if (event.key === "d") {
                interval = setInterval(moveRight, 1);
            }
            if (event.key === "w") {
                interval = setInterval(moveUp, 1);
            }
            if (event.key === "s") {
                interval = setInterval(moveDown, 1);
            }
            }
        });
        document.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
            clearInterval(interval);
            both = 0;
            player.style.transform = 'rotate(' + 180 + 'deg)'
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your `const carAnimation = document.querySelector('.carAnimate');` will run on load, before any element has that class.

Comment: I added it in the javascript code right before the event listener

Comment: But the query selector has already run. You are searching for it before it exists, then adding the class, then trying to use the matched element (but it wasn't found originally because it didn't exist at that point). You need to run the querySelector after the class has been added.

Comment: Sorry I am getting confused by what you are saying. Can you show me what to put maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping all of your code inside the below document-content-ready function

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  //your entire js code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure your code will run after the document's load is complete. you can do that by checking readyState like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

    <body>
        <div  class="game">
            <div class="car"></div>
            <div class="npcCar"></div>
            <div class="npcCar npcCar2"></div>
            <div class="npcCar npcCar3"></div>
        </div>
        <button class="start">Start!</button>
        <div class="controlContainer">
            <button class="btn pause"></button>
            <button class="btn play"></button>
            <button class="btn restart"></button>
            <button class="btn help"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="helpModal hidd">
            <div class="modal hidden">
                <button class="close-modal">&times;</button>
                <h1>Help</h1>
                <p>
                  HOW TO PLAY:
                    Use WASD to the arrow keys to move the red car around.
                    You need to avoid hitting the blue cars.
                    When you hit a car you will automatically lose
                    The longer you last the more points you get
                    Good luck racer!
                </p>
              </div>
        </div>
       
        
        <style>
            @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald&display=swap');
    
            *{
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
    
            body {
                display: flex;
                min-height: 100vh;
                width: 100%;
                background-color: rgb(69, 169, 240);
                font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
            }
    
            .game{
                position: absolute;
                left: calc(50% - 450px/2);;
                height: 600px;
                width: 450px;
                border: 3px solid black;
                border-radius: 5%;
                background: url('road.png');
                overflow: hidden;
            }
    
            .start{
                position: absolute;
                height: 30px;
                width: 150px;
                background-color: rgb(1, 255, 1);
                border: 3px solid black;
                border-radius: 5%;
                font-size: 15px;
                font-weight: bold;
                top: 600px;
                left : calc(50% - 150px/2);
                transition: 0.5s;
            }
            .start:hover{
                background: red;
            }
    
            .controlContainer{
                padding: 5px;
                width: 120px;
                height: 120px;
                border: 3px solid black;
                border-radius: 5%;
                background-color: lawngreen;
            }
            .btn{
                height: 50px;
                width: 50px;
                border: 2px solid black;
                border-radius: 50%;
            }
            .play{
                background-image: url('play.png');
            }
            .pause{
                background-image: url('pause.png');
            }
            .help{
                background-image: url('help.png');
            }
            .restart{
                background-image: url('restart.png');
            }
    
    
            .animate{
                animation: road linear infinite 0.5s;
            }
            .hidden{
                display: none;
            }
    
            @keyframes road{
                0%{
                    background-position-y: 0px;
                }
                100%{
                    background-position-y: 600px;
                }
            }
            .modal {
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                width: 45%;
                background-color: white;
                padding: 6rem;
                border-radius: 5px;
                box-shadow: 0 3rem 5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
                z-index: 100000000;
            }
            .close-modal {
                position: absolute;
                top: 1.2rem;
                right: 2rem;
                font-size: 5rem;
                color: #333;
                cursor: pointer;
                border: none;
                background: none;
            }  
            
            .car{
                position: relative;;
                height: 120px;
                width: 60px;
                border-radius: 5%;
                top: 435px;
                background: url('Player (1).png');
                transform: rotate(180deg);
                z-index: 100000;
                
            }
            .npcCar{
                width: 60px;
                height: 120px;
                background: url('obsacle.png');
                position: relative;
                left: 15px;
                top: -300px;
            }
    
            .npcCar2{
                top: -420px;
                left: 195px;;
            }
    
            .npcCar3{
                top: -540px;
                left: 375px
    
            }
    
            .carAnimate{
                animation: vroom 0.8s linear infinite;
            }
            .carAnimate2{
                animation: vroom 0.8s linear infinite;
            }
            .carAnimate3{
                animation: vroom 0.8s linear infinite;
            }
            @keyframes vroom{
                0%{
                    top: -120px;
                }
                100%{
                    top: 600px;
                }
            }
        </style>

         <script>
        'use strict'

        if (document.readyState === "complete") {
    
            const startBtn = document.querySelector('.start')
            const pauseBtn = document.querySelector('.pause')
            const playBtn = document.querySelector('.play')
            const restartBtn = document.querySelector('.restart')
            const helpBtn = document.querySelector('.help')
            const modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
            const closeModal = document.querySelector('.close-modal');
            const game = document.querySelector('.game');
            const player = document.querySelector('.car');
            const npcPlayer = document.querySelector('.npcCar');
            const npcPlayer2 = document.querySelector('.npcCar2');
            const npcPlayer3 = document.querySelector('.npcCar3');
            const carAnimation = document.querySelector('.carAnimate');
            const carAnimation2 = document.querySelector('.carAnimate2');
            const carAnimation3 = document.querySelector('.carAnimate3');
            let click = 0;
            let interval;
            let both = 0;
            let counter = 0;
    
    
            //onLoad
            window.addEventListener("load", () => {
                player.style.position = "relative";
                player.style.left = '195px';
                player.style.top = '485px';
            });
    
            // Start the Game
            startBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
                console.log('button clicked');
                game.classList.add('animate');
                click+=2;
                npcPlayer.classList.add('carAnimate')
                npcPlayer2.classList.add('carAnimate2')
                npcPlayer3.classList.add('carAnimate3')
    
                carAnimation.addEventListener('animationiteration', () => {
                    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
                    left = random * 90 + 15;
                    carAnimation.style.left = left + "px";
                    counter++;
                    console.log(counter)
                });
                carAnimation2.addEventListener('animationiteration', () => {
                var random1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
                left = random1 * 90 + 15;
                carAnimation2.style.left = left + "px";
                counter++;
                console.log(counter)
                });
                carAnimation3.addEventListener('animationiteration', () => {
                var random1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
                left = random1 * 90 + 15;
                carAnimation3.style.left = left + "px";
                counter++;
                });
                
            });
    
    
            //Pausing the Game
            pauseBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
                console.log('button clicked');
                if(click>1){
                    game.classList.remove('animate');
                    click--
                }
                console.log(click)
            });
    
            //Resuming the Game
            playBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
                console.log('button clicked');
                if(click===1){
                    game.classList.add('animate');
                    click++;
                    console.log(click);
                }
                
            });
    
            //Opening the Help Model
            helpBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
                console.log('modal clicked')
                modal.classList.remove('hidden')
            });
            //closing the help modal
            closeModal.addEventListener('click', function(){
                console.log('button clicked')
                modal.classList.add('hidden')
            });
    
            //Moving Functions
            function moveLeft() {
                var left = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(player).getPropertyValue("left"));
                var transform = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(player).getPropertyValue("transform")); 
            
                if (left > -0) {
                player.style.left = left - 2 + "px";
                player.style.transform = 'rotate(-' + 215 + 'deg)'
                }
            }
            function moveRight() {
                var left = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(player).getPropertyValue("left"));
                if (left < 385) {
                player.style.left = left + 2 + "px";
                player.style.transform = 'rotate(' + 215 + 'deg)'
                }
            }
            function moveUp() {
                var top = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(player).getPropertyValue("top"));
                if (top > 0) {
                player.style.top = top - 2 + "px";
                player.style.transform = 'rotate(' + 180 + 'deg)'
                }
            }
            function moveDown() {
                var top = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(player).getPropertyValue("top"));
                if (top < 490) {
                player.style.top = top + 2 + "px";
                player.style.transform = 'rotate(' + 180 + 'deg)'
                }
            }
            
    
            //Make the pLayer move
            document.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
                if (both == 0) {
                both++;
                if (event.key === "ArrowLeft") {
                    interval = setInterval(moveLeft, 1);
                }
                if (event.key === "ArrowRight") {
                    interval = setInterval(moveRight, 1);
                }
                if (event.key === "ArrowUp") {
                    interval = setInterval(moveUp, 1);
                }
                if (event.key === "ArrowDown") {
                    interval = setInterval(moveDown, 1);
                }
                if (event.key === "a") {
                    interval = setInterval(moveLeft, 1);
                }
                if (event.key === "d") {
                    interval = setInterval(moveRight, 1);
                }
                if (event.key === "w") {
                    interval = setInterval(moveUp, 1);
                }
                if (event.key === "s") {
                    interval = setInterval(moveDown, 1);
                }
                }
            });
            document.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
                clearInterval(interval);
                both = 0;
                player.style.transform = 'rotate(' + 180 + 'deg)'
            });

          }
    
        </script>
```